# Where to find the maven dependency for postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, maven

I use postgreSQL for a jsf application with JOOQ. I want to upgrade the postgreSQL for my application.I have updated the postgreSQL version on my windows from 9.5 to 10. Now i want to add a jar in the application to test. On [this link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql) i only find the jars till 9.4.x and than the 42.x series starts.

1) What is the jar for postgreSQL 10 and how do i know/find it?

2) My current application has 9.3-1102-jdbc41 dependency in the pom file. Does it means its postgreSQL 9.3?

Regards

Comment: The JDBC driver has a different version number than the Postgres server. 42.2.2 **is** the most current driver and will work with Postgres 10. The versioning scheme of the driver was [changed with 42.0.0](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/faq.html#version-change)

Answer (score 2):

For postgreSQL 10  you can use the below maven dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```